# Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice Exception Handler not returning HTTP Status Text

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a `GlobalExceptionHandler` that catches exceptions and returns a HTTP Error codes.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    ...

    // 404 - Not Found
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public void requestHandlingNoHandlerFound(HttpServletRequest request, Exception exception) {
        logger.error("Error Not Found (404): " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    ...

}
```

This works correctly and responds with a `404`. But the HTTP response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 
X-Application-Context: application:8080
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 14:36:52 GMT
```

But should return:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Application-Context: application:8080
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 14:36:52 GMT
```

The `Not Found` part is missing. This is the same for other errors. e.g. `500 - Internal Server Error`

Any ideas in how to include this?

**Update:**
Downgrading from Spring Boot 1.4.0 to 1.3.7 fixed this

Comment: I really, really hope you mean Spring Boot 1.4.0 -> 1.3.7

Answer (score 3):

From the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes):

> #### Server header
>
> The Server HTTP response header is no longer set unless the `server.server-header` property is set.

This seems like it might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, what would this need to be set to?

Comment: Hah, my bad - applies to something completely different. This looks like a regression, and it would probably be worth reporting a bug for it.

Comment: From http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html: RFC 7230 states that clients should ignore reason phrases in HTTP/1.1 response messages. Since the reason phrase is optional, Tomcat no longer sends it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
```

by extending this class you can override default spring behavior.

```
@ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class,EntityNotFoundException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(final RuntimeException ex,final WebRequest request) {
        final MyError myError= new MyError (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, myError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
}
```

`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)` is ok, but to get more control over response use `ResponseEntity`. Also by extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` you get access to bunch of preconfigured exception handlers.

Comment: I'll give this a go. Thanks :)