# Add reason phrase back in spring-boot 1.4.x

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

As noted [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6548) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746717/spring-boot-controlleradvice-exception-handler-not-returning-http-status-text), the latest version of Spring Boot (1.4.x) does not return the reason phrase due to the new version of Tomcat.

Unfortunately I am constrained by some legacy code that I cannot influence, and I need to add the "OK" reason phrase back to my responses.  Any idea how to do this?  If it was a header, it would be easy to modify with an `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.  But with the status line, I cannot even find the code where the status line is written.

I really don't want to have to (indefinitely) downgrade to old tech.  Hopefully someone knows a way to add this back in.

Comment: Pathc tomcat or use the tomcat version that still has support for this (or don't use Tomcat but Jetty).

Comment: Ugh.  I've added `<tomcat.version>8.0.37</tomcat.version>` to my pom.  But it stinks to forever pin your project to old tech.  I can't believe they didn't leave a way to re-insert this.

Comment: Tomcat bugzilla here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60183

Answer (score 4):

Add the following attribute to your `Connection` in `conf\server.xml`:

```
sendReasonPhrase="true"
```

In Tomcat 8.5.x the reason phrase was no longer sent by default.

Answer (score 3):

To add reason phrase back to spring-boot's embedded tomcat simply declare the following bean in your app config:

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(
                (TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> connector.setProperty("sendReasonPhrase", "true"));
        return factory;
    }
```

Works since Spring-Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE and untill embedded tomcat will be updated to 9.x version https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61160